# How to swap text entered in two text boxes?

Tags: android, android-edittext, swap

I need to create a button and two text boxes wherein the text boxes take input from user. On clicking the button, the text in the two text boxes should get swapped. Please help me with the swapping part. 
After

```
String text1=edtxt1.getText().toString();
String text2=edtxt2.getText().toString();
```

(getting the two texts entered)
what should i do?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to do this?

```
String text1 = edtxt1.getText().toString();
String test2 = edtxt2.getText().toString();
edtxt1.setText(text2);
edtxt2.setText(text1);
```

If not, then I don't completely understand what you're asking :-)